# How to define case class in Scala using case..match?

Tags: scala

How do I define case class in Scala using case..match?

```
sourceType match {
  case "elastic" => {
    case class Element(query_id: String,
                       elastic_source: ElasticSource)
  }
  case "csv" => {
    case class Element(query_id: String,
                       csv_source: ElasticSource)
  }
}
```

Comment: Define the case class as usual. Then *use* it to create instances inside the `match` block.

Comment: @Bergi: Example?

Comment: See FlorianBaierl's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you are doing is possible. You have to define the case class first and use it afterwards. To add variation you could use an Enumeration or define different case classes (maybe extending a base 'Element' class). This would be one - of many - possibilities:

```
object SourceType extends Enumeration {
    type SourceType = Value
    val Csv, Elastic = Value
}
case class Element(query_id: String, source: ElasticSource, `type`: SourceType)

// then you can do sth like this: 
val yourElement = Element(query_id, elastic_source, 
   sourceType match {
      case "elastic" => SourceType.Elastic
      case "csv" => SourceType.Csv
      case _ => // do sth else
})
```

Comment: Why is it `type` and not type?

Comment: Because `type` is a reserved word in scala so you can't use it to name your variables (same with e.g. `class`)

Comment: Well since that is the enumeration you'd have to define yourself maybe a missing import?

Comment: Ok, and finally it says that cannot resolve `query_id` in `Element(query_id`.

Comment: Sure, you will have to put your own variable name there :) the real id of your future Element object. It is a bit hard to help you there without knowing more of the code you're writing tbh.

Comment: I putted another name like `query_id1`, but the same issue. In general I do not understand this solution.

Comment: `query_id` cannot be specified explicitly in my case.

Comment: I think you have a more general problem of understanding what it is I am proposing. Tim has explained it quite well in his solution. You cannot define the case classes inside the match case since Scala is a "**compiled** language", which does not work like "**interpreted** languages" (e.g. Python and JavaScript - at least in most implementations). That is why you have to define your `Element` class before using it. My solution makes the distinction during run-time using an Enumeration and Tim's solution uses a trait that he extends with two different - specialized - case classes.

Comment: For my solution to **compile** correctly (not sure if it does what you want though!!) you would have to write something like this: `val yourElement = Element("yourQueryId", ElasticSource(), //...` (that is if the `ElasticSource` is a case class as well - I didn't find any documentation for it so it is probably a class you wrote on your own?)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because case classes are types, and all types are defined at compile time not run time. All you can do at run time is choose between different types. The closest to what you describe involves creating the two case classes in advance:

```
sealed trait Element
case class ElasticElement(query_id: String, elastic_source: ElasticSource) extends Element
case class CsvElement(query_id: String, csv_source: ElasticSource) extends Element
```

Your code decides between these to options based on `sourceType`, but from your comments you don't know the value of `query_id` or the `ElasticSource` at this point. So you need to use `sourceType` to create a function that will return the appropriate class once you know these values:

```
val builder = sourceType match {
  case "elastic" =>
    (id: String, source: ElasticSource) => ElasticElement(id, source)
  case "csv" =>
    (id: String, source: ElasticSource) => CsvElement(id, source)
}
```

When you know the `queryId` and `source`, you can use the `builder` to create your element(s):

```
val element: Element = builder(queryId, source)
```

This `element` with be either `ElasticElement` or `CsvElement` depending on the value of `sourceType` given earlier. You can determine which one of these you have by using `match`:

```
element match {
  case e: ElasticElement =>
    println(e.elastic_source)
  case e: CsvElement =>
    println(e.csv_source)
}
```